# Cleaning up overlapping edges for distinction from node to node

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

Is there anyway you can clean this up so it's clear that the p$_1$ and p$_3$ are distinct along their on respective branches from t=1 to t=2?

Moving the location of either one looks goofy and I'm not experienced enough to find the correct command to make it clearer their respective branches don't overlap.

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,wrapfig,graphicx,scrextend,sectsty,verbatim,tikz,tkz-berge}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]

\SetUpVertex[Lpos=-90]

\tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {shape=circle, fill=black, minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt}

        }

%t=1

\Vertex[x=0,y=1.5]{S$_0$}

\Vertex[x=1,y=1.5]{mS$_0$}

\Vertex[x=1,y=2]{uS$_0$}

\Vertex[x=1,y=1]{dS$_0$}

%t=2
\Vertex[x=2,y=2.5]{u$^2$S$_0$}
\Vertex[x=2,y=2]{umS$_0$}
\Vertex[x=2,y=1.5]{m$^2$S$_0$}
\Vertex[x=2,y=1]{dmS$_0$}
\Vertex[x=2,y=.5]{d$^2$S$_0$}
%t=1
\Edge[label  = $\widetilde{p}_1$](S$_0$)(uS$_0$)
\Edges[label = $\widetilde{p}_2$](S$_0$,mS$_0$)
\Edges[label = $\widetilde{p}_3$](S$_0$,dS$_0$)
%t=2
%u
\Edges[label = $\widetilde{p}_1$](uS$_0$,u$^2$S$_0$)
\Edges[label = $\widetilde{p}_2$](uS$_0$,umS$_0$)
\Edges[label = $\widetilde{p}_3$](uS$_0$,m$^2$S$_0$)
%m
\Edges[label = $\widetilde{p}_3\,\widetilde{p}_1$]
(mS$_0$,umS$_0$)
\Edges[label = $\widetilde{p}_2$](mS$_0$,m$^2$S$_0$)
\Edges[label = $\widetilde{p}_3$](mS$_0$,dmS$_0$)
%d
\Edges[label = $\widetilde{p}_3\,\widetilde{p}_1$](dS$_0$,m$^2$S$_0$)
\Edges[label = $\widetilde{p}_2$](dS$_0$,dmS$_0$)
\Edges[label = $\widetilde{p}_3$](dS$_0$,d$^2$S$_0$)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would colour-coding the different branches and their labels be acceptable?

Comment: I'd prefer not, but if that's something I could easily do, why the heck not try it? How would I implement it?

Comment: I'm not certain of the exact code, but perhaps something like ````\Edges[label=$stuff$,color=red]```` for the relevant lines?

Comment: That doesn't bring the p$_3$ forward from the lowest layer branch, but it's a good idea

Comment: Could you possibly sketch up something showing what you'd like it to look like? Just to make it clearer.

Comment: Also, you may want to look into packages designed for drawing trees. I'm personally not familiar with ````tikz-qtree```` or ````forest````, but I've seen others recommend them.

Comment: I think I've found my solution simply by spreading more, thanks ulysses!

Comment: To help others who find this question in the future, could you share your solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}    
\usepackage{lipsum,wrapfig,graphicx,scrextend}
\usepackage{sectsty,verbatim,tikz,tkz-berge,amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,tkz-graph}
 \usetikzlibrary{trees,fit,shapes,arrows, calc}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{quote}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
    \GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
    \SetUpVertex[Lpos=-90]
      \tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {shape=circle, fill=black, minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt}
        }
      %t=1
        \Vertex[x=0,y=1.5]{S$_0$}
        \Vertex[x=1,y=1.5]{mS$_0$}
        \Vertex[x=1,y=2]{uS$_0$}
        \Vertex[x=1,y=1]{dS$_0$}
      %t=2
        \Vertex[x=2,y=3]{u$^2$S$_0$}
        \Vertex[x=2,y=2.5]{umS$_0$}
        \Vertex[x=2,y=1.]{m$^2$S$_0$}
        \Vertex[x=2,y=.5]{dmS$_0$}
        \Vertex[x=2,y=0]{d$^2$S$_0$}
        \Vertex[x=2,y=1.75]{udS$_0$}
      %t=1
        \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={->,font=\scriptsize,above,sloped,midway}}
         \Edge[label  = $\widetilde{p}_1$](S$_0$)(uS$_0$)
         \Edges[label = $\widetilde{p}_2$](S$_0$,mS$_0$)
         \Edges[label = $\widetilde{p}_3$](S$_0$,dS$_0$)
      %t=2
                %u
            \Edges[label = $\widetilde{p}_1$](uS$_0$,u$^2$S$_0$)
            \Edges[label = $\widetilde{p}_2$](uS$_0$,umS$_0$)
            \Edges[label = $\widetilde{p}_3$, color=red](uS$_0$,udS$_0$)
                %m
            \Edges[label = $\widetilde{p}_1$, color=blue](mS$_0$,umS$_0$)
            \Edges[label = $\widetilde{p}_2$](mS$_0$,m$^2$S$_0$)
            \Edges[label = $\widetilde{p}_3$,color=blue](mS$_0$,dmS$_0$)
                %d
            \Edges[label = $\widetilde{p}_1$,color=red](dS$_0$,udS$_0$)
            \Edges[label = $\widetilde{p}_2$](dS$_0$,dmS$_0$)
            \Edges[label = $\widetilde{p}_3$](dS$_0$,d$^2$S$_0$)
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

All we have done is spread out the final nodes more so that the p$_n$ statements can be seen. Otherwise they cover over one another and cannot be seen.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you provide a full working/compilable answer? Please have a look to [How do I write a good answer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: please tell me if that is satisfactory so I can learn how to do this correctly haha

Comment: Of course. Remove `\begin{quote} %(tri) stock's path` and replace `\end{tikzpicture` with `\end{tikzpicture}` then it works for me and everyone could copy-and-paste-and-compile your code. Could you add some explanation what you have done? That would be great.

Comment: ... and you can add a screenshot of your solution. (6th symbol from the left.)

Comment: Okay, I think I added all the things!